# Generic type polymorphism confusion?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have an abstract factory like so:

```
public abstract class DAOFactory {
    public abstract EntryDAO<EntryDTO> getEntryDAO();
    ...
}
```

With my DAO and DTO interfaces like so:

```
public interface EntryDTO extends GenericDTO {
}

public interface EntryDAO<T extends EntryDTO> extends GenericDAO<T, Serializable> {  
}
```

And my implementation like so:

```
public class EntryDTOImpl implements EntryDTO {
}

public class EntryDAOImpl<T extends EntryDTO> extends GenericDaoImpl<EntryDTOImpl, ObjectId> 
 implements EntryDAO<T> {
}
```

Now, if I create a factory and override the `getEntryDAO` method like so:

```
public class MyDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {   
    @Override
    public EntryDAO<EntryDTO> getEntryDAO() {
        try {
            return new EntryDAOImpl<EntryDTOImpl>();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I get a compile time error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from EntryDAOImpl to EntryDAO

**EDIT**

I've updated my abstract factory like so:

```
public abstract <T extends EntryDTO> EntryDAO<T> getEntryDAO();
```

And made the change in my factory implementation:

```
@Override
public <T extends EntryDTO> EntryDAO<T> getEntryDAO() {
    try {
        return new EntryDAOImpl<EntryDTOImpl>();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting the compile time error:

> `Type mismatch: cannot convert from EntryDAOImpl<EntryDTOImpl> to EntryDao<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the abstract method this way (notice `?` instead of `T`):

```
public abstract EntryDAO<? extends EntryDTO> getEntryDAO(); //should work for you
```

I recreated the scenario the way I understood it: *returning `subclass1<subclass2>` as `interface1<interface2>`*

For example, this works well:

```
public static List<? extends CharSequence> dostuff1() { 
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```
public <B extends CharSequence> List<B> dostuff2() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

This gives the same compile-time error that you got: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String> to List<B>`

Comment: Thanks - why can't I use an interface as my parametrized type, and have an implementation be substituted?

Comment: During runtime, the program wouldn't know if `EntryDTOImpl` is a type of `T`. But it knows `T`, so you have to call it `T` in the function if you want to return it. This will compile: `return new EntryDAOImpl<T>();`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is that you're trying to return an `EntryDaoImpl<EntryDTOImpl>`, which is a subtype of  `EntryDao<EntryDTOImpl>`, but not of `EntryDao<EntryDTO>`, which is the return type of the method.

**Solution:**

I believe you want to change the return type of the `getEntryDao` method to

`EntryDAO<? extends EntryDTO>`.

Comment: I've made the suggested changes, but am still having problems. Please see my edits.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the return type from `EntryDao<T>` to `EntryDao<? extends T>`. That will do the trick:

```
@Override
public <T extends EntryDto> EntryDao<? extends T> getEntryDao() {
    try {
        return new EntryDAOImpl<EntryDTOImpl>();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dao;
}
```

Now as a justification, suppose `EntryDao<T>` has methods that return `T` like

```
T load(Serializable id);
```

and methods that accept `T` like

```
void save(T t);
```

Now assume `PersonDTO extends EntryDTO`, and  `CarDTO extends EntryDTO`.

If `EntryDao<EntryDTO>` were assignable from `EntryDao<EntryDTOImpl>`, it would also be assignable form `EntryDao<PersonDTO>` and  `EntryDao<CarDTO>`.

Then you could do:

```
EntryDao<EntryDTO> x = new EntryDao<PersonDTO>();       // currently this is a compile time error
```

If that were legal, you could do:

```
x.save(new CarDTO());   // a run time error, because x can only save Persons, not Cars
```

But what is `EntryDao<? extends EntryDTO>`? It is just EntryDao with all `T`-accepting methods like `save(T)` removed.

Comment: Can you explain why I need to do this? Why can't I just use `T`?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean by 'all `T`-accepting methods like `save(T)` removed'. By saying `EntryDao<? extends T>` I'm saying, accept any type that extends `T`, `T` being the upper bound. How's that different to saying `EntryDao<T>` if `T` is `<T extends EntryDto>`? I don't think you can use `T` as the matching parameterized type - and that's the issue. Even in your example, I'm still required to cast like so: `return (EntryDao<? extends T>) new EntryDAOImpl<EntryDTOImpl>();`.